# Increasing the size of console output display

Tags: winapi, windows-xp, console-application

Can we change/increase the size of console output to view large size of data in console application at once?

Comment: i would be interested in the from code part

Comment: @Kate I would like to do it using code so the change would be temporary.

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be different ways to Rome:

1. This should be the recommended way I would think, cause the name says it all: [GetConsoleWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683175%28VS.85%29.aspx) as is demonstrated [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/1481/).
2. A quick hack might be the windows API function [SendInput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646310). If you simulate Alt+Enter, you could probably fullscreen the active window.
3. [Here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/56723844-d189-4718-bca4-b7bf64d6fca6) are some propositions using API calls from user32.dll

Answer (score 0):

Check out the `SetConsoleScreenBufferInfoEx` API. It takes a `CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFOEX` as input and that has a dwSize member which contains the size of the console screen buffer, in **character columns and rows**.

MSDN for SetConsoleScreenBufferInfoEx Function: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686039(v=VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I once used a small hack that is first setting the console's output buffer and then trying to find the console window and resize it. It worked well on XP, I never tested it on newer Windows versions.

```
HANDLE h = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
SMALL_RECT sr;
sr.Top  = 0;
sr.Left = 0;
sr.Bottom = 10;
sr.Right  = 79;
SetConsoleWindowInfo(h, TRUE, &sr);
TCHAR title[512];
GetConsoleTitle(title, 512);
HWND hWnd = FindWindow(NULL, title);
if(hWnd != NULL) {
    HWND hWndInsertAfter = NULL;
    UINT nFlags = SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOZORDER;
#if 0   // Don't move?
    nFlags |= SWP_NOMOVE;
#endif
    SetWindowPos(hWnd, hWndInsertAfter , 40, 350, 0, 0, nFlags);
    SetForegroundWindow(hWnd);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are using the command prompt window, right click it's label on the task bar and click the Properties option.

Comment: OP explicitly states he is looking for code how to accomplish this, not GUI actions